# RewriteRule - loop redirection

Tags: mod-rewrite, loops

i need help with this 2 rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# folder/script.php?A=1&B=2  ->  xyz/1/2 (REDIRECT)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^A=([^&]+)&B=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^folder\/script\.php$ /xyz/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# xyz/1/2  ->  folder/script.php?A=1&B=2 (REWRITE)
RewriteRule ^xyz\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$ /folder/script.php?A=$1&B=$2 [L]
```

- First I need "REDIRECT"
  FROM: efectorelativo.net/folder/script.php?A=1&B=2
  TO: efectorelativo.net/xyz/1/2
- Then i need "REWRITE" not "REDIRECT"
  FROM: efectorelativo.net/xyz/1/2
  TO: efectorelativo.net/folder/script.php?A=1&B=2

EDIT: (working code, thanks to Gumbo)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# folder/script.php?A=1&B=2  ->  xyz/1/2 (REDIRECT)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?A=([^&]+)&B=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^folder\/script\.php$ /xyz/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# xyz/1/2  ->  folder/script.php?A=1&B=2 (REWRITE)
RewriteRule ^xyz\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$ /folder/script.php?A=$1&B=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Yeap, this would make a loop. What are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking how can i fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) in *THE_REQUEST* instead of the current URL:

```
# folder/script.php?A=1&B=2  ->  xyz/1/2 (REDIRECT)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\?A=([^&]+)&B=([^&\ ]+)\ 
RewriteRule ^folder/script\.php$ /xyz/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```